# Trying to do a dm command with msg.mentions.users.first, but it's not working

Tags: discord.js

```
    if(msg.content.startsWith("&%walcome")){
        const mentionid = bot.users.cache.get(`${msg.mentions.users.first().id}`)
            const up = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#C8CAF9')
            .setTitle('Sup')
            .setThumbnail(`${msg.mentions.users.first().displayAvatarURL()}`)
            .setDescription(`Sup **${msg.mentions.user.first().tag}**, be welcome to MFPA Official Discord Community. If you joined withouht knowing wth is this server, I will explain: this is the official server of the series with the same new, that is available on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWZRrkidNF5Se8fkgGzoxgg)`)
            .addFields(
                {name: 'Fun in server', value: 'That is right, dear new member, you can actually have fun in this channel! We have some custom emojis, events, chat (sometimes is dead but eh-). But!, first of all, do not forget to go to #verify (823564914605686844) to get access to the server'},
                {name: 'Specific Announcements', value: 'You can receive specific announcements (Faded Pics, Betro Ideas and Dani Sounds) if you are interested in the whole production of the series'},
                {name: 'If you need help, just dm a staff member', value: 'Thats right, if you need help, you can contact one of the Staff Team member, they will reply when available'}
            )
            .setFooter(`Sent by ${msg.author.tag}, bot made by dani bear#3606`, `${msg.author.displayAvatarURL()}`)
               mentionid.send(up)
            }
})
```

So, this code is not working, and I don't know why. The error is `Cannot read property 'first' of undefined`, but I already used this and it worked-

If you could help I would be grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in `.setDescription('Sup **${msg.mentions.user.first().tag...)}'`.Its `msg.mentions.users.first()`(Missed an 's' in 'users'). Also, if you are going to use the mentioned User object again and again, store then in a variable, and then access the properties of that.

Comment: Always here to help!